ST_DWithin rows underestimated
I use ST_DWithin in a WHERE clause.
The row estimate is always 1. Independent of center point and radius. This causes problems in more complex queries because the query planner uses nested loops because it expects only 1 row when in reality more than 1000 rows are returned.
Any hints on how to improve the row estimation?
This is a minimal example to reproduce:
CREATE TABLE locationtable (
  location geography(Point,4326) NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX index_locationtable ON locationtable USING gist (location);

WITH data AS
(
    SELECT generate_series(1, 2000)::float / 2000 AS x
)
INSERT INTO locationtable(location)
SELECT ST_SetSRID( ST_MakePoint(6.953101+x, 50.935173+x), 4326 )::geography
FROM data;

VACUUM ANALYZE locationtable;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * from locationtable
WHERE ST_DWithin(locationtable.location, 'SRID=4326;POINT(6.953101 50.935173)', 110000);

This yields this query plan:

https://www.pgexplain.dev/plan/3981dc99-8a14-4f83-b2fe-ef43360b4b94
https://explain.depesz.com/s/63L1

Seq Scan on locationtable  (cost=0.00..25065.00 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=7.781..8.904 rows=1676 loops=1)
  Filter: st_dwithin(location, '0101000020E6100000BC2363B5F9CF1B40158DB5BFB3774940'::geography, '110000'::double precision, true)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 324
Planning Time: 0.700 ms
Execution Time: 8.973 ms                                                                                                        

PostGIS version: 3.5 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
PostgreSQL version: PostgreSQL 17.0 (Debian 17.0-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit

This is a bit tricky. Before PostgreSQL 12 functions were black boxes to the optimizer, simply because there was no way to determine what they would return and how the returned rows relate to table stats. Arguably, PostGIS' core functionality suffered most from this as geometric predicates are extremely hard to predict - in terms of histogram comparisons. The only way for PostGIS to gain momentum here was to trick the planner into looking up index stats via e.g. geom1 && geom2 AND _ST_<function> (bbox lookup and _'ed function call) inside the top-level SQL API.

With PostgreSQL 12 the architecture for support functions was added to the core - in fact, mostly with PostGIS in mind - which allows SQL level functions to invoke C level functions that in turn provide the optimizer with better cost and volume estimations for this specific function call in order to do its job. PostGIS currently has a single such C function that (conditionally) covers most SQL predicate functions and which is supposed to look up cached table/index stats with the given input in mind (e.g. the distance threshold) to produce better estimates.

This is where it gets tricky, as following the hooks for these support functions from core to core through caches, table stats and index lookups is a rabbit hole I haven't gone down, yet - and so all I can suspect is that either the support function returns nothing below a threshold of affected rows/table counts, or for static inputs like yours in general, or that it doesn't get called at all for the planners decision to run a Seq scan anyways. The old trick, however, still works, and will at least return some row estimates from index stats.

On my setup (Postgres 14, Postgis 3.3.2, Windows) , switching st_dwithin to st_distance(a, b) <= 110000, which I think is equivalent, yields a 6K row estimate but keeps the seq scan plan. I didn't post this as an answer, because I can't explain why.

also : moving the geometry litteral to a temp table kicks in a bitmap_heap_scan (with no benefits, as Zegarek pointed out)

You placed all 2000 of your generated points on a diagonal line running in 0.0005° steps North-East, the furthest one sitting 1° or 131_198 meters away. Only 16% of your points stick out the 110_000 meter range. It doesn't make much sense to consult the index in order to locate 84% of rows in the table - a sequential scan makes way more sense.
Normally, PostgreSQL only allows operator-based conditions to lean on an index and the way PostGIS manages to make that work with functions is by hiding an operator call inside them. In this case, it turns this:
WHERE ST_DWithin(  locationtable.location
                 , 'SRID=4326;POINT(6.953101 50.935173)'::geography
                 , 110e3);

into something like this:
WHERE locationtable.location && _st_expand( 'SRID=4326;POINT(6.953101 50.935173)'::geography
                                           ,110000)
  AND _ST_DWithin( locationtable.location
                  ,'SRID=4326;POINT(6.953101 50.935173)'::geography
                  ,110e3);

And if you try to type that out "manually", you might see a different estimation (my test uses 100k points):
demo at db<>fiddle



QUERY PLAN




 Seq Scan on public.locationtable  (cost=0.00..2501986.00 rows=33333 width=32) (actual time=0.039..624.949 rows=83801 loops=1)


   Output: location


   Filter: ((locationtable.location && '0101000020E6100000BC2363B5F9CF1B40158DB5BFB3774940'::geography) AND _st_dwithin(locationtable.location, '0101000020E6100000BC2363B5F9CF1B40158DB5BFB3774940'::geography, '110000'::double precision, true))


   Rows Removed by Filter: 16199


 Planning Time: 0.305 ms


 Execution Time: 639.981 ms



Suggesting the operator is used for the estimation, which is further confirmed by a comment the source in postgis/postgis /gserialized_estimate.c:L46:
Depending on the operator and type, the mode of selectivity calculation
will be 2D or ND.

- geometry && geometry ==> 2D
- geometry &&& geometry ==> ND
- geography && geography ==> ND

The 2D mode is put in effect by retrieving the 2D histogram from the
statistics cache and then allowing the generic ND calculations to
go to work.

The histogram is in pg_stats:
SELECT ord
      ,st_astext(translate(a_bound,'{}','')::geography)
FROM pg_stats
cross join lateral string_to_table(histogram_bounds::text,':') with ordinality as u(a_bound,ord)
WHERE tablename = 'locationtable'
  and attname='location'
order by ord;

Thing is, when the planner decided to pick the seq scan, it might've ditched the operator entirely because it'd only duplicate _st_dwithin()'s job for no reason. They answer the same question, but && only compares bboxes, while _st_dwithin() answers based on precise, shape-to-shape distance. Even if && isn't discarded entirely, as @geozelot pointed out, the estimation function might not even kick in in a seq scan scenario. In either case you seem to be left with the default estimation, eyeballed purely based on table size. I'm getting N*0.0001 - 10 rows expected from a 100k table.
You can use the same trick of adding the && explicitly to try and tame the planner. Your mileage may vary, because if the index kicks in (in an earlier demo, I bumped up the statistics target all the way up to 10k and it did), the row estimation might go down again.
